# Set title attribute with condition and using angular translate

Tags: angularjs, attributes, angular-translate

I am using title attribute with some condition and my code is

```
<li title="{{admin ? 'purchase license pack':''}}"><span translate>pack.details</span></li>
```

Here when the admin is true then it shows **purchase license pack**. But how to make that one to i18n keys by using translate filter.
I tried this,

```
<li title="{{admin ? '{{'purchase.pack'|translate}}':''}}"><span translate>pack.details</span></li>
```

But It shows parsing error.
How to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error was natural since you were trying to interpolate the interpolation. However, You were quite close.. Try This :

```
<li title="{{admin ? ('purchase.pack'|translate) : ''}}"><span translate>pack.details</span></li>
```